# low volume sound even with the volume up to max?

Tags: 11.10, laptop, volume-control

This wasn't the case before, but recently I get relatively low volume sound in my laptop, both the integrated speakers and the headphones, even with the volume up to max. I checked `alsamixer` and everything is up to max. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the upper right side of the screen, you can see a symbol of speaker. Click it. If the volume level is high there, leave it and go to *Sound preferences* and increase output volume.